# Compiler complains about unassigned variable after switch on enum

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I have the following enumerator:

```
enum Foo { Bar, Baz };
```

In the following code, the compiler aborts with the error:

```
use of unassigned local variable 'str'
```

The code:

```
string str;
Foo foo = Foo.Bar;

switch (foo)
{
    case Foo.Bar: str = "a"; break;
    case Foo.Baz: str = "b"; break;
}

str.ToLower();
```

The `switch` covers all the possible values of the enumerator. But the compiler still thinks that `str` might be unassigned. Why is that? Of course I could put a `default` case in there, but that would be wrong, since errors are not caught at compile-time. For example, if the `Foo` enum is modified later on and a new value added, *then* it would be nice to get a compiler error. If I use a `default` case, then the error is not caught when recompiling.

I suppose there is no way to get the compiler to accept a `switch` without a `default` case *and* raise an error if `Foo` is extended later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suppose there is no way to get the compiler to accept a switch without a default case and raise an error if Foo is extended later on?

This is correct. Long story short, the reason why the compiler does this is that it is possible to assign `foo` a value that is not one of a valid `enum Foo`s values by typecasting an `int`, making it possible to bypass all cases of the `switch`.

The solution that I use in situations like this is to add an assertion:

```
switch (foo)
{
    case Foo.Bar: str = "a"; break;
    case Foo.Baz: str = "b"; break;
    default: Debug.Assert(false, "An enum value is not covered by switch: "+foo);
}
```

Comment: The assertion looks like the best idea in this case.

Comment: You could use `Debug.Fail(...)` instead of `Debug.Assert(false, ...)`. How does this last switch section go on? Will you assign a dummy value (like `null`) to `str`, and `break`? Or will you `throw`? You cannot "fall through"; the endpoint of a switch section must be unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are statically typed and type checked. But the checking does not extend to ensure that enum values only assume defined values. In fact, for `Flags` enums variables often do not assume any single defined value.

Like that:

```
Foo f = (Foo)1234; //valid
```

And that's why the `switch` can pick the `default` case at runtime and `str` could end up being used in an uninitialized state.

Some languages have stronger constructs than .NET enums such as Haskell and F#.

Answer (score 1):

The enum is essentially an int and any int value could be assigned to it.  This usually doesn't happen but is why you need to handle the default case or simply declare the string with a default value (like null)

Answer (score 1):

> Of course I could put a default case in there, but that would be wrong

That would be according to good practices. Your enum can still contain other numeric values, because enums in C# are only compile time layer above the underlying numeric representation - think `const` fields. `Foo f = (Foo)int.MaxValue;` will still compile and run, but now you don't have a switch case for it.

Depending on your interface, you may either put a default case with an exception there, define `str` with null, or an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to just initialize str with an empty string in your first line. the compiler can't (or won't) try to analyse the switch logic that deeply.